# Web Service Testing & Automation - Open Source Tools

Tags: web, service

I am looking for Web Service Functional Testing + Automation - Open Source Tool.

SOAP UI - Free for functional testing. If you want to extend it for Data Driven Testing you need to buy Pro Version

For Automation - I am planning to use TestNG Framework plus custom java coding for web service test automation.

My Question

1. Are there any other open source tools which you have used in your previous projects which can be leveraged for Web Service Functional + Test Automation. I am looking for previous project experience / success based on such tools.

The target system is on Java platform based system. I had earlier worked on .NET 2.0/WCF services. I had used VSTS for Web Service Automation. I initially thought of idea of using VSTS but for licencising and cost related factors i opted for TestNG & Custom Coding.

Comment: Why would you use selenium for web service testing?

Comment: I have used SoapUI for automated functional testing of webservices but its a pro version. Did you try Postman?

Comment: when you say Web Service its a little ambiguous , could you clarify if this is a REST API  or an actual webpage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For functional testing, I've used soapUI and WFetch.  WFetch has worked well for the most part, soapUI is great, although doesn't seem to handle kerberos, by which most of the web services that I need to test are protected. For just manual, soapUI has normally been my clear winner.

When it comes to automation, I'll admit, I found soapUI rather confusing when I needed to have multiple parameter values.  Visual Studio test has been alright for this purpose, but, I think that it could still be a little more intuitive.

A couple of projects ago, I started using my own code with NUnit as my driver for the automation.  This has worked well for the most part, although I've run into some fragility issues, which I hope to solve in the near future.  For manual testing, I've put together WinForms application template that can be easily modified to work as a custom tool for any RESTful webservice (haven't tried it using SOAP yet).  This has worked great for me so far.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at Selenium @ www.seleniumhq.org its open source and really flexible or you can have a look at jubula http://eclipse.org/jubula/  its an eclipse project for automated functional GUI testing for Java and HTML applications.

Comment: Selenium for Web service testing?